# Regex to exclude a specific string but not strings having the substring

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am currently in need of a regex that can exclude a specific string but not words that include that string. For example if you have a string made of 0's and 1's. Any string that contains any number of 1's and any number of 0's except 3 0's exclusively.

For example:

```
100100  pass
1000100 fail
00100   pass
000100  fail
0000100 pass
111000  fail
11100001 pass
```

I tried the following regex but it only accepts strings that can start with 1 but have to end with 0.

```
^(1*([0]{0,2}|[0]{4,}))$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?!.*?(?<!0)000(?!0))[01]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD3jL7/4)

Comment: It doesn't fail on 00001000

Answer (score 1):

You could create a regular expression that accepts your wanted pattern but it will be complicated. It will be easier if you create the negative regular expression `.*(1|^)000(1|$).*` and test if your string doesn't match this regular expression.

This is sample python code:

```
import re
r = re.compile("(1|^)000(1|$)")
tests = [
    "100100", "1000100", "00100", "000100", "0000100", "111000", "11100001"
]
for t in tests:
    print("%s %s" % (t, "fail" if r.search(t) else "pass"))
```

Result:

```
100100 pass
1000100 fail
00100 pass
000100 fail
0000100 pass
111000 fail
11100001 pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below lookarounds based regex.

```
^(?![10]*(?<!0)000(?!0)[10]*)[10]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vZ5sR8/2)

- `(?<!0)000(?!0)` Asserts that the `000` won't be preceded and followed by any but not of `0`